# Connecting Amazon SQS with ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-elb

I'm trying to design correct flow for my application on AWS platform. I have two components, first collecting queries from web and a second one is my backend.

I'm using Auto Scaling for both components. I'm also using ELB before first component and between first and second.

I'm wondering about SQS service. I'm not sure where shoud I install it.
This is my currnet flow.
[image]
Does ELB will queue up calls or should I install SQS before my backend? Or SQS is not solution for auto scaling solutions?

What is best practices for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elb is not going to queue your calls. The proper tool for that is sqs. The only thing with sqs is that you have to decide if ordering and lack of duplicates in messages is important or not. If it's important you should use FIFO sqs.

You can scale on sqs as explained in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-using-sqs-queue.html.

Comment: So if I understood correctly architecture will be look like: ELB -> first_scaling_group(EC2 frontend) -> ELB -> second_scaling_group(SQS -> EC2 backend).
Am I right?

Comment: @CezarySzulc Yes, its typical 2 tear architecture.